# Boto3, read gzip from s3 and print content

Tags: python

I'm trying to read a gzip file from S3 - the "native" format f the file is a csv. Ultimately, after uncompressing the file, I'd like to be able to "see" the content so I can read the number of lines in the csv and keep count of it.

My "basic" attempts are here - still just trying to print the contents of the file. This attempt just tells me that there is no such file or directory...

I know I'm also probably erroneously thinking the unzipped csv file will be in json format - but that's the next "issue" once I get to read the unzipped contents...

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'SMSUsageReports/eu-west-1/2018/01/02/001.csv.gz' 



import gzip
import boto3
import json
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('snssmsreports')
for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='SMSUsageReports/eu-west-1/2018/01/02'):
    json_object = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket.name, Key=obj.key)
    file_name = obj.key
    obj = bucket.Object(file_name)
    file_body = obj.get()["Body"].read()

    # gzip stuff here
    f=gzip.open(file_name,'rb')
    file_content=f.read()
    #print file_content

    #jsonFileReader = json_object['Body'].read()
    jsonDict = json.loads(file_content)
    #table = dynamodb.Table('SNS')
    #table.put_item(Item=jsonDict)
    print('{0}:{1}'.format(bucket.name, obj.key))
    print(jsonDict)
```

OK, So I updated my code as follow:

```
import zipfile
import gzip
import boto3
import io
import json

import pandas as pd


s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('snssmsreports')
for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='SMSUsageReports/eu-west-1/2018/01/02'):
    json_object = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket.name, Key=obj.key)
    file_name = obj.key
    obj = bucket.Object(file_name)

    s3_client.download_file(bucket.name, file_name, '../../tmp/file.gz')

    gzip_name = '../../tmp/file.gz'
    # gzip stuff here
    with gzip.open(gzip_name,'rb') as f:
        file_content=f.read()
    str_file = str(file_content)

    csvfile = open('../../tmp/testfile.csv','w') 
    csvfile.write(str_file) 
    csvfile.close()  

    #table = dynamodb.Table('SNS')
    #table.put_item(Item=jsonDict)

    #pandas csv reader
    df1 = pd.read_csv('../../tmp/testfile.csv')
    print(df1)

    #print('{0}:{1}'.format(bucket.name, obj.key))
    #print(file_content)

    #table = dynamodb.Table('SNS')
    #table.put_item(Item=jsonDict)
```

This does not throw any errors anymore, but the output only has one row and 135 columns, so panda is not liking the actual content of the csv, or my conversion to str() is not the right way to do it?

Comment: 1. Download the file 2. Extract the file 3. Read using csv reader/pandas

Comment: OK, So I did the following:

Comment: So my casting to str() of the file_content is definately causing the pandas issue since \n's are now literal after the str cast. But the file write operation does not want to create the csv file if the content is not string?

Answer (score 0):

OK, issue was the opening of the file for write - to write bytes I had to open file as wb...

```
csvfile = open('../../tmp/testfile.csv','wb') 
csvfile.write(file_content) 
csvfile.close()
```